# Passing command line parameters to VB6 IDE in console app

Tags: vb6

I have a VB6 console app and it uses command line parameters.  For debugging, I would like to be able to start it from the IDE and ideally be able to pass it those parameters to see how it normally operates.  I realize I could set a breakpoint at the appropraite place and use the Immediate window to set the values outside the command line, and I have used a couple of other workarounds in the past, but is there a way to do this as if I had actually started it as a console app?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Select Project | Properties, select the Make tab, enter the command line params in the Command Line Arguments text box.  These will only apply when run in the IDE.

Comment: Great, thanks!  Now that you mention it, I recall seeing this in the past, but I haven't done much VB6 for a few years, and I have forgotten a lot.

Comment: Actually, Command Line Arguments on the Make tab are design-time only.  They do *not* get compiled into the exe.