# How to step thourgh a second vb6.exe that is called from the main vb6.exe

Tags: debugging, vb6

I have a Main VB6 application that is calling another VB6 application. The Sub application is crashing when it is called from the main VB6 application. I how can i step though the second application to debug the error. I know in .net you can attach to another process and step through, is there a way to do the same thing in vb6?

The second application is being called with:

```
ShellEx(App.path & "\main.exe", essSW_SHOWDEFAULT, PassedParameters)
```

Comment: Open the sub project in the IDE, [set command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1267974/11683) that you would have passed and press F8.

Comment: That worked, to bad cant "Attach" Thanks for the help.

Comment: FYI, in .Net you cannot "attach" from main project to second project too. You have to use similar approach there too.